# jsr 303 validated all fields in object

Tags: json, spring-mvc, bean-validation, jsr

suppose i hava two view files(`jsp`s) and one class(`BudgetControlRegisterDto`)

**BudgetControlRegisterDto**

```
public class BudgetControlRegisterDto implements Serializable {
@NotNull(message = "{NotNull.java.util.Date}")
    private Date demandReceiveDate;

@NotNull(message = "{NotNull.java.util.Date}")
    private Date demandOriginalDate;

@NotNull(message = "Start date {NotNull.java.util.Date}")
    private Date startDate;
@NotNull(message = "End date {NotNull.java.util.Date}")
    private Date endDate;


// setter and getter 
}
```

In one view file i want to validate `startDate` and `endDate`
and in other view file i want to validate `demandOriginalDate` and `demandReceiveDate` using json ajax. when validation occurs i get validation message for all fields with below code:

**controller class's method** this is testing code used by both view files(`jsp`s)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addnewdemand.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody BudgetControlRegisterDto addNewDemand(@Valid @ModelAttribute("bcrDto") BudgetControlRegisterDto bcrDto,Errors errors){
    log.info("addNewDemand invoked!");
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            log.info("has errors");
            bcrDto.setFieldsErrors(errors.getFieldErrors());
            return bcrDto;
        }


    return bcrDto;
    }
```

**.js file** this is testing code used by both view files(`jsp`s) below code is ajax response code

```
if(response.fieldsErrors != null) {
    html ='<div class="ui-message-error">';
    for(var i= 0; i<response.fieldsErrors.length; i++) {
        html+='<span>'+response.fieldsErrors[i].defaultMessage+'</span><br/>';
    }
    html+='</div>';
    $("#bcrForm_message").html(html);
}
```

**Question** why m i getting validation message of all fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the situation where `groups` takes place. Here is a good tutorial about [them](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/08/validation-groups-in-spring-mvc.html).

The first thing you need to change is to add groups attribute to your `@NotNull` annotations.

```
public class BudgetControlRegisterDto implements Serializable {
@NotNull(message = "{NotNull.java.util.Date}",groups={First.class})
    private Date demandReceiveDate;

@NotNull(message = "{NotNull.java.util.Date}",groups={First.class})
    private Date demandOriginalDate;

@NotNull(message = "Start date {NotNull.java.util.Date}",groups={Second.class})
    private Date startDate;
@NotNull(message = "End date {NotNull.java.util.Date}",groups={Second.class})
    private Date endDate;


public interface First {};
public interface Second {};

// setter and getter 
}
```

the second one is to change from `@Valid` to [`@Validated`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) because `@Valid` doesn't support validation groups.

controller's method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addnewdemand.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody BudgetControlRegisterDto addNewDemand(@Validated(BudgetControlRegisterDto.First.class) @ModelAttribute("bcrDto") BudgetControlRegisterDto bcrDto,Errors errors){
    log.info("addNewDemand invoked!");
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            log.info("has errors");
            bcrDto.setFieldsErrors(errors.getFieldErrors());
            return bcrDto;
        }


    return bcrDto;
    }
```